# How to get a method called with different parameters?

Tags: java, android, methods, android-context, instanceof

I'm fetching 3 `String` values from the database and then I'm converting it to `Long` and then I'm calculating a difference and then putting this calculated `Long` value in a method as parameter. I'm using [FastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter).

The `filterRequests(List <Long> l)` is a method in `MainActivity` which do the logic of filtering requests/content based on the long `l`.

entire adapter:

```
public class GRModelClass extends AbstractItem<GRModelClass, GRClass.ViewHolder>{

    private static final ViewHolderFactory<? extends ViewHolder> FACTORY = new ItemFactory();

    String postedBy, postedTime, currentLat, currentLng, utcFormatDateTime, userEmail, userID;
    String startDateTimeInEpoch, endDateTimeInEpoch;
    DatabaseReference primaryDBKey;
    long ms;
    String itemID;

    public GRModelClass(){}

    public GRModelClass(String postedBy, String postedTime, String currentLat, String currentLng, String utcFormatDateTime, String userEmail, String userID, String startDateTimeInEpoch, String endDateTimeInEpoch, DatabaseReference primaryDBKey) {
        this.postedBy = " " + postedBy;
        this.postedTime = postedTime;
        this.currentLat = currentLat;
        this.currentLng = currentLng;
        this.utcFormatDateTime = utcFormatDateTime;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userID = userID;
        this.startDateTimeInEpoch = startDateTimeInEpoch;
        this.endDateTimeInEpoch = endDateTimeInEpoch;
        this.primaryDBKey = primaryDBKey;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("pBy", postedBy);
        result.put("cLat", currentLat);
        result.put("cLng", currentLng);
        result.put("utcFormatDateTime", utcFormatDateTime);
        result.put("userEmail", userEmail);
        result.put("userID", userID);
        result.put("startDateTime", startDateTimeInEpoch);
        result.put("endDateTime", endDateTimeInEpoch);

        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.recycler_view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.sr_layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(final ViewHolder holder, List list) {
        super.bindView(holder, list);

        holder.postedBy.setText(postedBy);
        holder.postedBy.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.startDateTimeInEpoch.setText(startDateTimeInEpoch);
        holder.startDateTimeInEpoch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.endDateTimeInEpoch.setText(endDateTimeInEpoch);
        holder.endDateTimeInEpoch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        MainActivity.filterButton.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                holder.geoQuery = holder.geoFireReference.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(holder.currentLatDouble, holder.currentLngDouble), 5);

            holder.geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    primaryDBKey.child(key).child("startDateTimeInEpoch").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                                holder.startTimeDateInEpochLong2 = Long.parseLong(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                                holder.now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                                holder.diffNowsdtel.add(holder.startTimeDateInEpochLong2 - holder.now);
                                Log.d("log1", String.valueOf(holder.diffNowsdtel));

                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if(holder.mContext instanceof MainActivity){
                                            ((MainActivity)holder.mContext).filterRequests(holder.diffNowsdtel);
                                            Log.d("log2", String.valueOf(holder.diffNowsdtel));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 1500);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * our ItemFactory implementation which creates the ViewHolder for our adapter.
     * It is highly recommended to implement a ViewHolderFactory as it is 0-1ms faster for ViewHolder creation,
     * and it is also many many timesa more efficient if you define custom listeners on views within your item.
     */
    protected static class ItemFactory implements ViewHolderFactory<ViewHolder> {
        public ViewHolder create(View v) {
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }
    }

    /**
     * return our ViewHolderFactory implementation here
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public ViewHolderFactory<? extends ViewHolder> getFactory() {
        return FACTORY;
    }


    // Manually create the ViewHolder class
    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView postedBy, userID, currentLt, currentLn, requestID, postedFrom;
        TextView startDateTimeInEpoch, endDateTimeInEpoch, diffNowsdtelTV;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        long difference, differenceCurrentStartTime, handlerGap;
        long startTimeDateInEpochLong2;
        public static long now;
        List<Long> diffNowsdtel;
        Context mContext;
        DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase;
        GeoFire geoFireReference;
        GeoQuery geoQuery;


        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            postedBy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postedBy);
            startDateTimeInEpoch = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.startTimeDateInEpoch);
            endDateTimeInEpoch = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.endTimeDateInEpoch);
            diffNowsdtelTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.diffNowsdtelTV);

            this.mContext = itemView.getContext();

        private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                    = (ConnectivityManager) itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem** is that when I'm logging `log1`, I'm getting all the 3 values shown in `Logcat`, but when I'm logging `log2` only the last calculated value is getting shown and that is the value using which `filterRequests(Long l)` is getting called.

**Update** - after updating the adapter code, `log1` and `log2` now shows this:

```
 D/log1: [2197]
 D/log1: [2197, -1007]
 D/log1: [2197, -1007, 4003]

 D/log2: [2197, -1007, 4003]
```

`filterRequests()` method is the method in which the logic to filter content based on time is done. The parameter which goes in `filterRequests()` is `holder.diffNowsdtel` which has 3 `long` values for now and do it should do the logic based on it.. if the long value is `<=900` the content which has the long value `-1007` should be shown and when long value is `>900`, the content which has the long value `2197` and `4003` should be shown.

here's the code:

```
public void filterRequests(final List<Long> l) {

    final int size = l.size();

            Log.d("lng", String.valueOf(l));

                    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        if (chkBoxLiveRqsts.isChecked()) {



                                    firebaseDatabase.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                                                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                                                    if (l.get(i) <= 900) {
                                                    ...       
                                                    } else {
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                progressDialogAdding.dismiss();
                                            } else {
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                ...
                            });
                        } else if (chkBoxSFLRqsts.isChecked()) {
                            fastItemAdapter.clear();
                            firebaseDatabase.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                                                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                                                    if (l.get(i) > 900) {
                                                        ...

                                                    } else {
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                progressDialogAdding.dismiss();
                                            } else {
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                ...
                        } 
                    } else {
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(coordinatorLayout, "No internet connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.show();
                        progressDialogAdding.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
}
```

Log value of `lng`:

```
D/lng: [2197, -1007, 4003]
```

**What I want** is that the `filterRequests(Long l)` method should use all the values of `holder.diffNowsdtelTV.getText().toString()` and do the logic using them.

I'm sorry for ambiguous question. Please help me with this issue!

Comment: What about some [mcve] here ? It seems to be a simple problem ...

Comment: @AxelH what do you mean by that, bro?

Comment: The amount of code you have included is a lot. Also, as AxelH said, it sounds like a simple problem. If you could remove all the unnecessary code and include the ones that are needed then it would be helpful for other people to answer your question. Moreover, it's not really clear what you are trying to do in `filterRequests(..)`. Read the link he provided

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet I have edited it to my best... please take a look

Comment: First, you are speaking about `MainActivitiy.filterRequest(Long l)` but all I can find is `MainActivitiy.filterRequest(final List<Long> l)` then, what I understand if I translate the methods you want is [What are captured variables in Java Local Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22025161/4391450). And that could be resume in an example of 5line. PS : Don't _bro_ me please ;)

Comment: I should have add that I think having that many nested local class might be a bad design. You should think about create some Class to clean that code.

Comment: Last think ... there is some strange thing in your code, could you explain how `holder.diffNowsdtel = holder.startTimeDateInEpochLong2 - holder.now;` can compile if `holder.diffNowdtel`is declared has `List<Long>`  ...

Comment: @AxelH Thanks for pointing out the silly mistakes in the question... I've edited it. Any help now?

Comment: About what, you have your answer or not? This question is closed...

Comment: @AxelH this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41023421/6144372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you are doing**

In your `ViewHolder` `diffNowsdtel` is declared as `long` (which saves latest value) whenever you are logging **log1** `Logger` displays (latest value from `diffNowsdtel` so your log displays different values because `bindView` calls many times whenever you are updating your row or complete dataset)

```
D/log1: -22136
D/log1: -22403
D/log1: -25094
```

Inside `onMenuItemClick` you are fetching value directly from your `TextView` which is now -25094 that's why you have only one value in your `TextView` and log says

```
D/log2: -25094
```

**What you should do**

Set Tag using `holder.diffNowsdtelTV.setTag(your database key or row_id)` and inside your `onMenuItemClick` get your tag using

```
Object someTagName = (Object) holder.diffNowsdtelTV.getTag();
```

Now fetch your 3 `String` values from the database using value stored in `someTagName` and then do your calculations.

**Edit**

Actually you need 3 values to do your calculation, while in your current logic you only have the latest value stored in `diffNowsdtel`. So now you need a logic to store trice your values somewhere and inside `onMenuItemClick` use them but if you will go to save trice your values you have to change your `diffNowsdtel` to `long[]` or `List<Long>` and save your every value in it on every `bindView` call which needs some logic so simplest way is to pass your unique database column say primary key and save it in your `GRModelClass`

```
String primaryDbKey;

public GRModelClass(String primaryDbKey, ...) {
    this.primaryDbKey = primaryDbKey;
    ....
}
```

Inside your `onMenuItemClick` use `primaryDbKey` to fetch your 3 `String` values from your database table(which you are doing somewhere else) and then do your calculations.

---

**Edit**

You made a list with `Long`, both `List` and `Long` are not primitive data types.
In your question you are comparing primitive and non primitive data types, for comparison both sides of a comparator should be of same data types.

**What you are doing:**

```
if (l.get(i) <= 900)
```

Here `l.get(i)` returns a `Long` value where as `900` is integer value.

**What you should do:**

Simply compare your `l.get(i)` with `Long` by doing `900L`

```
if (l.get(i) <= 900L)
```

Or

```
if (l.get(i) > 900L)
```

Comment: hey... thanks for answering. I am still confused about **What you should do** part. Please write some code or explain more clearly. Please? Thanks again.

Comment: based on your '**Edit**', I tried it and I have updated the adapter and the `logcat` in the question. `log2` also shows 3 values now just like `log1`, but all the 3 values are same.

Comment: It is because you are still using `diffNowsdtel` in `onDataChange` which is **-29601**. You should calculate your result based on your 3 `String`   values and use them. Do not save its value in variable if you do you will have the latest value in your variable or make an `long[]` or `List<Long> `and save your 3 values in it

Comment: Salaam bro... you just edited a question of mine. That's what I tried after your previous comment here. :(

Comment: com start our discuss in chat

Comment: please have a look at edited question... I have updated it.

Comment: Accept this answer as your actual problem has been solved, then ask a separate question with given details or move this conversation to chat room

Comment: done... please help with the new quesion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023421/how-to-compare-values-stored-in-listlong-with-a-long-value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130033/discussion-between-haris-qureshi-and-hammad-nasir).

Answer (score 1):

Try to set initialize the value you want within the onBindView

```
   Log.d("diffNowsdtel", holder.diffNowsdtelTV.getText().toString());
    final String val = holder.diffNowsdtelTV.getText().toString();

            MainActivity.filterButton.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    if(holder.mContext instanceof MainActivity){
                        ((MainActivity)holder.mContext).filterRequests(Long.parseLong(val));
                        Log.d("diffNowsdtel2",val);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Okay, then can you post the entire adapter code to the question?

Comment: I've edited my solution. Try that and see what happens

Comment: Set val prior to first log, use in both logs, any change?

Comment: @While-E nope. No change. `log1` printed all the 3 values while `log2` printed only the last calculated value. See edited question.

Comment: @While-E I tried this approach too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17837183/6144372, but it also shows just the last calculated value :(

Comment: @While-E please help, dude.

Answer (score 1):

You have a statically defined object called filterButton in MainActivity.  Every time bindView is called for a new view, it is replacing the menu item listener for that button.  So when you click that menu item, it is only calling the handler you set on for the last item that bindView was called for.  That's why you only see one log entry when that filter button is pressed.

Comment: Please tell me about how can I get the feature start working?

Comment: You could try setting the item click listener one time when you create the filter button in the activity, rather than in bindView.  The listener can get all the items in the list and loop through them, making the call to filterRequests for each item.  That way, each time you click the button, the listener will call filterRequests for all your items, and you should get 3 log messages.

Comment: but then I have to set the `holder.diffNowsdtelTV.getText().toString()` statically to pass it into `filterRequests()` as a parameter and calling it from `MainActivity`. This will again show only take/show only the last calculated value of `holder.diffNowsdtelTV.getText().toString()`. :/