# How to compare values stored in List<Long> with a long value?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, arraylist, long-integer

I'm retrieving some long values and storing it in `List<Long> l`.

Here is the logged out value of `List<Long> l`:

```
D/lng: [2197, -1007, 4003]
```

Then, I'm trying to compare it with `long` values like `<=900` or `>900`.

Here's how:

```
    public void filterRequests(final List<Long> l) {

            final int size = l.size();
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < size; i++){

            }
            Log.d("lng", String.valueOf(l));

            if (l.get(i) <= 900) {
                 // do the logic when l <= 900       
            } else {
            }

    }
```

The problem is that `if (l.get(i) <= 900)` or `if (l.get(i) > 900)` both is not working even when the `l.get(i)` has values both `<=900` and `>900`, see: `D/lng: [2197, -1007, 4003]`

**UPDATE**: @HarisQureshi 's answer worked but the problem is that cause of the `for` loop, the `if` condition inside is getting called 3 times while I want it to get called only once. So, I want to know that is there a way to define `for` loop above that code and then use the `i` in the `if (l.get(i) <= 900)` and `if (l.get(i) > 900)` conditions?

Comment: Too much irrelevant code. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Example: [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/I3pgHv)

Comment: Is the list passed to `filterRequests()` updated after the method returns? Remember that your `onDataChange()` handlers are called at some later time, and they reference that *same* list. Declaring the parameter `final` does not make the list immutable. Don't confuse the "Java is pass-by-value" with the fact that it is the *reference* value that is passed by value. The list itself is to be considered as passed-by-reference, so the method and the caller *share* the same list.

Comment: Create an example without using Android /firebase or other. Pure Java and local class. This will be simpler and you might even find the answer yourself... This is explain on the link of Andreas.

Comment: @AxelH have a look now... I have done the same as suggested by you

Comment: First, you do twice the same thing ... you have two loop to check once if `>=900` and then the opposite `<900`. Just use the else part insteand of a second loop. But this is working so try to gave something _Verifiable_

Comment: What does it mean is there a way to define for loop above that code and then use the `i` in the `if (l.get(i) <= 900) and if (l.get(i) > 900)` conditions?

Comment: @HarisQureshi see the edited code, is that possible?

Comment: Using that you will have `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because now `i = 2`

Comment: @HarisQureshi yeah... this is the error I'm getting while trying to do this. What should I do then?

Comment: use `l.get(size -1)` it will give you `4003`

Comment: @HarisQureshi but I want all the values stored in `l` not just `4003`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130106/discussion-between-haris-qureshi-and-hammad-nasir).

Comment: @HarisQureshi please come to the chat

Answer (score 0):

You made a list with `Long`, both `List` and `Long` are not primitive data types.
In your question you are comparing primitive and non primitive data types, for comparison both sides of a comparator should be of same data types.

**What you are doing:**

```
if (l.get(i) <= 900)
```

Here `l.get(i)` returns a `Long` value where as `900` is integer value.

**What you should do:**

Simply compare your `l.get(i)` with `Long` by doing `900L`

```
if (l.get(i) <= 900L)
```

Or

```
if (l.get(i) > 900L)
```

Comment: Did you try to debug with above values?

Comment: @HarisQureshi Okay, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: @HarisQureshi it is working actually. The problem is that cause of `for` statement the loop is happening 3 times. Is there any way to specify `i` before and the use it in the `if (l.get(i) <= 900)` and `if (l.get(i) > 900)` conditions?

Comment: I couldn't understand, please elaborate in your question, what you want.

Comment: @HarisQureshi please see the edited part of the question

Comment: @HammadNasir Don't update question like this after your received and answer. And you should search how to use `if-else` because you seems to don't understand how those works.

Comment: @HarisQureshi [Here is a snippet](http://ideone.com/uzqZEw) showing that your answer doesn't change anything. Please tell me where I am wrong here.

Comment: @AxelH i do know that by adding `900L` doesn't solve the problem, but @HammadNasir said that **"The problem is that cause of for statement the loop is happening 3 times"**

Comment: @HarisQureshi So, you agree that your answer doesn't help since you only said **Simply compare your `l.get(i)` with `Long` by doing `900L`**

Comment: It should be, but once i read your thread i came to know it is same as comparing two `Long`'s