# Why is the method not over yet but the local variable no longer exists?

Tags: java

I am learning the 'Core Java' book about how the local inner class access variables from outer methods. While, I am confused about something.

The book provides a snippet of code here:

```
public void start(int interval, boolean beep)
{
    class TimePrinter implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            System.out.println("At the tone, the time is " + new Date());
            if (beep) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }

    ActionListener listener = new TimePrinter();
    Timer t = new Timer(interval, listener);
    t.start();
}
```

The book illustrate how the flow of control here as:

1. The `start` method is called.
2. The `listener` is initialized.
3. The `listener` reference is passed to the `Timer` constructor. **At this point, the `beep` parameter variable of the `start` method no longer exists.**
4. Moment later, the `actionPerformed` method executes `if (beep) ...`

I am just confused about why the beep no longer exists? I thought the outer start method is still not coming to the end }, the local variable could still live...

Comment: so, you are declaring a class within a method? I very much doubt this will compile to begin with.

Comment: @Stultuske eclipse does not throw any error on that topic

Comment: it is called local class, see [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html). The compilation is successful.

Comment: The point is that `TimePrinter.actionPerformed()` gets *executed* long time after the method has finished, mist likely from another thread...

Comment: point 3 is wrong. you can still print the value at the end of the method

Comment: @Stultuske Also, you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428186/use-of-class-definitions-inside-a-method-in-java) question for further information.

Comment: @Stultuske It's somewhat unorthodox, but that's valid Java. If you were to read the question fully, you would see that this is not even his code and that he's specifically asking about local classes.

Comment: @Michael yes, I did read that. I've also read posts of people that copied from a book, and ended up with four public classes in a single file, because they didn't realize they needed seperate files. Even when duplicating from a book, errors can come up

Comment: @Michael *sigh* dude, indeed, I was mistaken, which was pointed out several posts before yours. I merely responded to your "he copied it from a book, so it has to be right" point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is an exact quote from the book, the book is wrong. You are correct that the `beep` parameter of the `start` function does not go out of scope until the closing brace `}`. There is no special behaviour caused by the use of a local class.

---

In this scenario, a variable is said to have been ["captured"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025161/what-are-captured-variables-in-java-local-classes).

A variable needs to be either [final or "effectively final"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final) to be captured - i.e. it must never be reassigned.

In your case, you do not modify the value of `beep` so it is effectively final and eligible to be captured.

When you create the `TimePrinter` object, the value of `beep` is copied into its internal state. This is because the variable `beep` may have gone out of scope by the time it needs to be used.

The timer is started and the `start` method ends. The original `beep` has now gone out of scope. Every few seconds (depending upon `interval`) `actionPerformed` will now be called. The original `beep` *has* gone of scope, but we made a copy of its value so our function is still able to execute as we would expect.

That's pretty much the idea the author is trying to express.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler knows that `beep` is *effectively final* and can therefore be assumed to not change. It will then arrange to build the local object as something like:

```
    class TimePrinter implements ActionListener {
        // Capture the local variable in this instance.
        boolean instanceBeep = beep;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("At the tone, the time is " + new Date());
            if (instanceBeep) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
```

However, this will only work if the `beep` parameter is *effectively final*, i.e. it does not change and could even be declared `final beep` without breaking the code.

To confirm, just try something like:

```
public void start(int interval, boolean beep) {
    class TimePrinter implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("At the tone, the time is " + new Date());
            // Error:(17, 21) java: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final
            if (beep) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
    // Add this to see the compiler working it out.
    beep = false;
    ActionListener listener = new TimePrinter();
    Timer t = new Timer(interval, listener);
    t.start();
}
```

and see that the accessing of the `beep` parameter is now not allowed because it is no longer *effectively final*.

See official Oracle doc on [effectively final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class) or the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4).

Comment: @Michael - agreed - fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details!